# Simple animation using UIView.Animate

Tags: swift, animation, core-animation

I'm trying to create my custom activity indicator thing, this is what I have so far:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let center = view.center
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 180, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath

        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 20
        shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0


        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
            let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

            basicAnimation.toValue = 1
            basicAnimation.duration = 2

            basicAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
            basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            self.shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "key")
        }) { (finished) in
            if finished {
                self.shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
        }





    }
```

So, after the animation is completed, I will present a new controller or something. The issue is that the completion is being called immediately. So, how I can wait for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIView.animate()` and `CABasicAnimation` are two different things. The completion is being called right away because the `UIView.animate()` method does not know what is happening with the other. It sees no *standard* UIView animations and so fires the completion block.

One way to achieve this is to use an [`animationDidStop`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimationdelegate/2097259-animationdidstop?language=objc) delegate method. You need to set the animation delegate to the view, controller, then have it implement the relevant callback.

Add these two lines:

```
basicAnimation.setValue("strokeEnd", forKey: "animationID")
basicAnimation.delegate = self
```

Then make sure you conform the view controller to `CAAnimationDelegate` protocol (by adding that after `UIViewController` in its declaration) and implement this delegate method:

```
override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    if let animationID: Any = anim.valueForKey("animationID") {
        if animationID as String == "strokeEnd" {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
}
```

---

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27883059/8289095)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a delayed dispatcher with the delay exactly equal `duration`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
    // The job has to be done after animation
}
```

Alternatively you may use `CATransaction.setCompletionBlock`, but it needs some deeper knowledge about the `CA` itself and you may want to use the first option.